# Clearing temp Uploaded Files folder in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, filesystems, temporary-files

I was wondering what the best practice was for the following scenario:

A user uploads a file on page A. the file is stored in a unique temp folder (based on user GUID). The user is redirected to page B where validation of the file is performed and eventually redirected to page C.

All of these pages use the file(s) uploaded by the user.

Obviously, at some point I want to remove those files to prevent the server from getting stuffed with temp files. I've got a couple of solutions that come to mind, but I was wondering if there is a better solution/which one of those is the best.:

- Solution 1: Delete the file after the process is completed (in this case, on Page c). I don't think this is a good solution, because it's well possible that the user cancels his action somewhere halfway (page B). This would still cause temp files to stay on the server
- Solution 2: On onload of page A, do a check for in the main temp folder, and delete all files & folders which haven't been used in the last x days
- Solution 3 (which is probably the cleanest): write a small console app that will do the same as solution 2, and schedule it with windows task scheduler to run once a day at night
- Solution 4: Same as 3, but in a windows service. I'd think it's a bit overkill to create a windows service for that.

Now, I'm tempted to say 3 is the cleanest, but since it seems a bit overkill for the app I'm having, I think the combination of solution 1 & 2 make a good alternative.

Any suggestions / feedback?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say that a combination of ideas 1 and 3 are great. Allow the page to delete the file after a job has been completed (clear what you can as you go so you don't waste storage space). Then, have a "backup" scheduled task that runs once a day during the least active time of your website, and delete any spare files that are older than a threshold that you determine.

You don't need the overhead of a long-running process that deletes files once a day (solution 4).

Solution 2 particularly stands out to me as *bad* because it reduces the perceived performance website - deleting a file takes time, especially when the (HDD) disk is being thrashed.

Comment: Yes, I understand your point of view. But seing how we are talking about excel files of +/- 50 KB (all files need to use the same template) and certainly not more than 30 files a day AND flexibility is an important factor I think we might take the performance hit rather than having a seperate task which will also need to be redeployed on every server where we deploy the mini-site. Also if the temp folder changes, changes would have to be reflected in the 2 apps....